# Python:file:unbound method __str__() must be called with xDef instance as first argument (got classobj instance instead)

Tags: python

I have main file(generator.py) and I have resources as folder in same path which has multiple class files(CTDef.py,..) and each of them are invoked based on argument passed in command line executing main file(generator.py). When I trigger execution in command prompt, got the above subject error . I did check on __ini__file existence in resources folder to consider it as package and all the .py files in resources folder has only class methods(@class..).

In the main file, have included below sample code for import. please let me know  if there is any issue around here or let me know how to resolve this?
**Python version:** 3.7.3

code: from resources.CTdef import CTV1Def, CTV2Defs

CTdef is python file
CTV1Def is class name
CTV2Defs is another class name from same file

code:

```
def main(argv):
    def saveFile(CTVGenerator, recs):
        try:
            for i, chnk in enumerate(recchnks):
                cname = CTVGenerator.__str__(CTVGenerator)
                CTVs = CTVGenerator(chnk)
                myfile = open(save_dir + '{0}_{1}.xml'.format(cname, i), 'w+')
                myfile.write(CTVs.generate())
                myfile.close()
                print("done saving {0} CTVs containing {1} CTVs !".format(cname, len(chnk)))
        except Exception as exc:
            print("couldn't save {0} file : {1}".format(CTVGenerator, exc))

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="CTV XML Generator.  Used to generate XML files for import")
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument('-hr', help="generate the hourly files", action="store_true")
    ...
    ...
    recchnks = chunks(recs, num)
    if args.CTVs:
        try:
            print("creating CTV files... ")
            saveFile(CTVDefs, recchnks)
        except Exception as exc:
            print("couldn't save CTV file : {0}".format(exc))
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of [tree](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) or something equivalent on your project root directory so we can clearly understand your directory structure.

Comment: And please show us the code surrounding the call to `__str__` (it probably is through `str`).

Comment: def __str__(self):
        return "CTV_name"

Comment: That is the implementation of `__str__`; I am interested in how you're calling it (note that `str` calls `__str__` internally).

Comment: please edit your question with this code surrounded by triple backticks(\`\`\`)

Comment: Maxxik , I have edited the question and added the code